# How to re-arrange/manipulate data?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data set from a lab experiment. The data is now in this form:

```
ColumnID Soiltype Treatment Concentration1 Concentration2 Concentration3
1        Oh       Control   29             31             34
2        LOf      Treatment 100            99             94
3        Oh       Treatment 80             83             78
```

How can I manipulate the data such that it looks like the following:

```
ColumnID Soiltype Treatment Concentration
1        Oh       Control   29
1        Oh       Control   31
1        Oh       Control   34
2        LOf      Treatment 100
2        LOf      Treatment 99
2        LOf      Treatment 94
3        Oh       Treatment 80
3        Oh       Treatment 83
3        Oh       Treatment 78
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Look at the reshape package http://had.co.nz/reshape/introduction.pdf .  Your problem could be solved with `melt(id=c("ColumnID","SoilType","Treatment")`.

Comment: See, also, the examples in `?reshape`. `reshape(DF, direction = "long", idvar = "ColumnID", varying = list(4:6), v.names = "concentration")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes under the general category of reshaping data to long form (for your future google-fu reference):

```
library(reshape2)

melt(df, id.var = c('ColumnID', 'Soiltype', 'Treatment'),
         value.name = "Concentration")
#  ColumnID Soiltype Treatment       variable Concentration
#1        1       Oh   Control Concentration1            29
#2        2      LOf Treatment Concentration1           100
#3        3       Oh Treatment Concentration1            80
#4        1       Oh   Control Concentration2            31
#5        2      LOf Treatment Concentration2            99
#6        3       Oh Treatment Concentration2            83
#7        1       Oh   Control Concentration3            34
#8        2      LOf Treatment Concentration3            94
#9        3       Oh Treatment Concentration3            78
```

Removal of extra columns and ordering is left to the reader.